# file path and delete file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, file-io, express, path, filepath

I want to delete 3 files in `list_file_to_delete` but I do not know what is the path to put to "path to three files here"?. Do I need for loop/for in/forEach function to delete all or just need a string with 3 paths likely `var string = "...a1.jpg, ...a2.jpg,...a3.jpg"`? Thanks in advance

in `delete.js` file

```
var list_file_to_delete = ["/images/a1.jpg", "/images/a2.jpg", "/images/a3.jpg"]
fs.unlink(path to three files here, function(err) {console.log("success")})
```

this is `myapp` directory

```
 myapp
      /app
          /js
             delete.js
      /public
             /images
                    a1.jpg
                    a2.jpg
                    a3.jpg
      server.js
```

Comment: backticks are not quotes. Use them to surround code only.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`fs.unlink` takes a single file, so unlink each element:

```
list_of_files.forEach(function(filename) {
  fs.unlink(filename);
});
```

or, if you need sequential, but asynchronous deletes you can use the following ES5 code:

```
(function next(err, list) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error("error in next()", err);
  }
  if (list.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  var filename = list.splice(0,1)[0];
  fs.unlink(filename, function(err, result) {
    next(err, list);
  });
}(null, list_of_files.slice()));
```

Comment: thanks, and how's about path to files, I use /../public/images/a1.jpg not working

Comment: the path is relative to the directory you used `node yourscript.js` in, so if you call that in the `myapp` directory, you would unlink the files as "./public/images/a1.jpg" etc.

Comment: It works now, thanks so much. But I do not understand why because I think we use relative path in case public directory inside js directory

Comment: If you have set `public` as static folder in your server.js, then you have direct access to `./images/...`.  No need for relative path or even `/../public/images/...`. I hope I answered your question about folder directory.

Comment: Trust me Mike. They are hundreds of people who are just starting to learn NodeJS or any other technology for that matter. As long as the information provided is valid,  having a wide range of opinions and alternatives will save them hours of debugging. And I don't think it matters if a question is 3 years old. New information regarding a subject is always a good thing. 

Comment: i found ALLJs comment usefull ;)